# Need help about 'new' operator in C++

Tags: c++

I wanna understand about the *new* operator in C++ and what's going on my code.
I have 2 files A and B,both can be compiled.But I'm facing the error "*Segmentation fault*" when running binary of A.Binary of B is working fine.

What does the "new" operator do in file B ?

> File A

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    public:
    virtual void eat() { std::cout << "I'm eating generic food."<< endl; }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    public:
    void eat() { std::cout << "I'm eating a rat." << endl;}
};

void func(Animal *xyz){ 
    xyz->eat();
}

int main()
{
    Animal *animal ;
    Cat *cat ;
    func(animal);
    func(cat);
    return 0;
}
```

> File B

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    public:
    virtual void eat() { std::cout << "I'm eating generic food."<< endl; }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
    public:
    void eat() { std::cout << "I'm eating a rat." << endl;}
};

void func(Animal *xyz){ 
    xyz->eat();
}

int main()
{
    Animal *animal = new Animal;
    Cat *cat = new Cat;
    func(animal);
    func(cat);
    return 0;
}
```

The differences between file A and B are

```
Animal *animal = new Animal;
Cat *cat = new Cat;
```

Comment: When you define local variables in C++, like e.g. `animal` or `cat` in your examples, they are not automatically initialized but will have an *indeterminate* value. Using them in any way without initialization leads to *undefined behavior*. In the case of a pointer, it means it will point to a seemingly random location.

Comment: This is a very basic question... Read a book or Google it.

Comment: You are missing the basic very concept of what pointers are and do.

Comment: I do not want to explain. But because so many experts are here. I just started learning C ++ a few days ago. I will Google more before asking next time

Comment: As you continue studying C++ many other questions and doubts will arise ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator allocates memory for the object and then invokes the constructor to initialize it. In file A you do not initialize your objects, thus passing uninitialized pointers to `func`, leading to the segmentation fault.

Comment: He don't pass nullpointer. The pointer are not initialized, so the value is random. He should use `Animal animal` and pass the address `&animal`, to use the `func()` without the new operator.

Comment: No, they're not null pointer. And the behavior is undefined.